# How to convert Future[Seq[SomeClass]] to Json?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, future

In Play framework I'm using Slick with MySQL database, how could I convert query result (**Future[Seq[SomeClass]]**) to Json for further usage in jQuery Autocomplete. I can serialize **SomeClass** , but where should I use **.map**(or something else) ?

**Added**:

Model:

```
   package models
    import play.api.libs.json._

    case class Equipment(id: Long, name: String,area: String,kiMin: Double,kiMax: Double,cosFiMin: Double,cosFiMax: Double){

    implicit val equipmentWrites = new Writes[Equipment] {
    def writes(equipment: Equipment) = Json.obj(
    "id" -> equipment.id,
    "name" -> equipment.name,
    "area" -> equipment.area,
    "kiMin" -> equipment.kiMin,
    "kiMax" -> equipment.kiMax,
    "cosFiMin" -> equipment.cosFiMin,
    "cosFiMax" -> equipment.cosFiMax
    )

//also tried this for Seq

 /* def writes(equipment: Equipment): JsValue = {
    val equipmentSeq = Seq(
      "id" -> JsNumber(equipment.id),
      "name" -> JsString(equipment.name),
      "area" -> JsString(equipment.area),
      "kiMin" -> JsNumber(equipment.kiMin),
      "kiMax" -> JsNumber(equipment.kiMax),
      "cosFiMin" -> JsNumber(equipment.cosFiMin),
      "cosFiMax" -> JsNumber(equipment.cosFiMax)
    )
    JsObject(equipmentSeq)
  }*/

    }
    }
```

Controller:

```
   def auto(term: String) = Action {
    Ok(Json.toJson(equipmentDAO.get(term)))
  }
```

DAO:

```
def get(name: String): Future[Seq[Equipment]] = db.run((equipment.filter { _.name === name }).result)
```

**Added2:**

controller method:

```
def auto(term: String) = Action.async {
    val future: Future[Seq[Equipment]] = equipmentDAO.get(term)
    future.map { seqOfSomeClass =>
      Ok(Json.toJson(seqOfSomeClass))
    }
    }
```

Serializer:

```
implicit val equipmentWrites: Writes[Equipment] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").write[Long] and
      (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
      (JsPath \ "area").write[String] and
      (JsPath \ "kiMin").write[Double] and
      (JsPath \ "kiMax").write[Double] and
      (JsPath \ "cosFiMin").write[Double] and
      (JsPath \ "cosFiMax").write[Double]
    )(unlift(Equipment.unapply))
```

Comment: More details are needed. Are you using Play JSON framework, right? When you say "serialize SomeClass", you meant serialize to JSON, correct? Where this conversion needs to be done? In a Play Controller? Could you post the Controller code?

Comment: @virsox, added some info, don't understand what is  Play JSON framework I'm using Play 2.5, it includes Json, answer to other questions is "yes".

Comment: You should not try to "parse" a `Future[T]`, but parse `T` "inside" the `Future`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering that you understand how [Play Framework handles JSON](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson#JSON-basics) and already have [`Reads` and `Writes`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonCombinators) for `SomeClass`, you can do something like this in your controller:

```
def someAction = Action.async {
  val future: Future[Seq[SomeClass]] = ??? // get the future using Slick
  future.map { seqOfSomeClass =>
    Ok(Json.toJson(seqOfSomeClass))
  }
}
```

This will [serve a list of `SomeClass` in JSON](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonHttp#Serving-a-list-of-entities-in-JSON).

Comment: I've edited the post to show what I've done (after "Added2:"), but I'm still getting "No Json serializer found for type Seq[models.Equipment]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type." Where could be the problem?

Comment: This solution is working, I just needed to put **Writes** in companion object, thanks.